# Finding longest series with data bigger than 0, date of start and end of that series

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, numbers, series

I am looking for formulas in Excel which are:

1. count of longest series of numbers bigger than 0
2. date of the start of that series
3. date of the end of that series

Purpose - looking for longest series of snow depth bigger than 0 cm during winte season.

Here on Imgur is example of data table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/feka2.jpg

Snow depth is from 1 to 89 cm so far. If there is date without snow depth, there is empty cell. Cells are formating as number.

Date is in second row from D2:HO2.
Data for each winter are under date, so Winter 2023/2024 is from D3:HO3. Winter 2022/2023 is from D4:HO4 etc.

Count of longest series in column HP, start date in column HQ and end date in column HR.

Is possible to write formulas into HP, HQ and HR columns or should I do it manually?

Thank you for any help.

Regards,
Kenobi

I tried ask ChatGPT, but his formulas did not work. I still got error result. For example he send me this for count of longest series:

=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(D4:HO4);COLUMN(D4:HO4));IF(ISNUMBER(D4:HO4);COLUMN(D4:HO4))))

Comment: For your information, having a small representative sample data set for people to copy into their spreadsheets to play with is much better than posting an image of data.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Have you checked the logic of the formula? It checks for a number, but you want a number greater then 0. So have you tried changing ISNUMBER to >0

Comment: @P.b yes, I tried >0 logic instead of ISNUMBER, did not help

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((D4:HO4>0),COLUMN(D4:HO4)),IF((D4:HO4<=0),COLUMN(D4:HO4))))
```

Or

```
=LET(r,D4:HO4,
     c,column(r)
     MAX(
FREQUENCY(IF((r>0),c),IF((r<=0),c)))
```